# Switching Charactercase C

Tags: c

I am attempting to write a program that takes an inputted string and outputs the string in the opposite case. e.g upper case to lowercase and vice versa. unfortunately All I am getting as an output is a question mark with a square around it.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
char sentence[200], ch; 
    int x=0;
    int count =0;
    char oppo[200];
printf("Type something\n");
    while(ch != '\n'){
        scanf("%c", &ch);
        sentence[x] = ch;

        x++;
    }

x=0;

printf("\n");
for(count=0;sentence[count]=='\0';count++){
    if(islower(sentence[count])==0){
        oppo[count]=tolower(sentence[count]);
    }
    else
    {
        oppo[count]=toupper(sentence[count]);       
    }

}
x=0;
while(oppo[x]!='\0'){
    printf("%c",oppo[x]);
    x++;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Basic debugging techniques: Use a debugger and/or debug print statements to trace the execution of your program.

Comment: `sentence[count]=='\0'` --> `sentence[count] != '\n'`. That is, the condition operator is wrong and you don't store a NUL character anyway.

Comment: `while(ch != '\n')`... That invokes Undefined Behaviour since `ch` is not initialised and hence has a random value on the first loop.

Answer (score 0):

You do not add `'\0'` to `sentence` after reading it. So your check `sentence[count]=='\0'` may not satisfy and you would overrun the buffer.

In fact the condition in `for` loop should be

```
for(count=0; sentence[count] !='\0'; count++){
 ....
}
```

You can try using `scanf()` with `%s` to read string rather than reading character by character.